# is it faster to store logic in vuex or in vue composition api?

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I'm a hobby coder. im learning vue and i am wondering now if it would be faster to store app logic in vuex actions or in a composition api hook.

for explanation:
i wrote an electron app. this app reads a file and transforms it to an huge array. (size over 2000).
the logic thats stored in the vuex action takes one item of the array, changes it and replace it and stuff like that.
now for performance improvement im wondering if i should use better the composition api or stay at the vuex actions

i didnt place code in here because my question is not code specific. i want to know generaly if vuex could be slower than using the composition api

Comment: It's unlikely that the performance of the store will be a bottleneck or at least have a considerable impact on the performance. Your code that uses it will. It's safe to assume plain Vue reactivity has better performance than Vuex because the latter adds a layer over the former that inevitably has some overhead. But this doesn't mean that your own store will perform better than Vuex.

Comment: for explaination: i dont want to replace the vuex store. i love the store. but i have some functions in the actions section, that reciev some data, process it and than commit it to the mutations section. that actions could be stored in the vue hook section if the performance would be better

Comment: I doubt that this will help the performance, unless you dispatch thousands of actions per second. Sounds like the case of premature optimization. Another thing is that you don't need to put everything to global store if you don't need that.

Comment: ok, so i will keep my actions. it would be much work to transform the nessessarry components into composition components and outsource the actions to the hooks, annyway. if it isnt realy faster it would be useless. thank you for your opinion

Answer (score 0):

Use vuex, it's so fast and reactive, It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion